# jQuery 1.8 Get selected value from radion button group

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a radio button group on my page:

```
1<input type="radio" name="greeting" value="1"/>
2<input type="radio" name="greeting" value="2"/>
3<input type="radio" name="greeting" value="3"/>
4<input type="radio" name="greeting" value="4"/>
5<input type="radio" name="greeting" value="5"/>
```

I have some code to get the selected value from this group:

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
$("#btnAddEval").click(function () {
    $.fn.AddEval();
}).hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("addOver");
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("addOver");
});
```

});

```
jQuery.fn.AddEval = function () {
$("#dvMsg").hide();
$("#dErr").hide();
var agent = $("#selAgent option:selected").text();

if (agent == '(Select Agent)') {
    $("#divErr").show();
    return;
}

var gretting = $("input:radio[name=greeting]:checked").val();
var greetingcmt = $("#txtGreeting").val();
$("#dvMsg").show();
```

};

This is the way that the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/) shows to get this value. When I test this and select any of the 5 button I always get greeting = "". I cannot seem to retrieve the value.

Comment: Your code works good in jQuery 1.8.3. Matbe you have some other JS errors on the page.

Comment: Yup. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ULDRK

Comment: The page is still very simple and just starting out - no other errors on the page. Also - there are textboxes on the page and I am getting the values from them just fine.

Comment: Must be something in your app's logic, then. Show your code.

Comment: OK - I put all the code above. The debug point is on the line"  var gretting = $("input:radio[name=greeting]:checked").val();